# XML / JSP HTTP 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page at line 22 - what is the root cause?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat

InventoryReport.jsp has to analyse the inventory.XML file in order to generate a rapport that will lists each books in store, generate a warning for each book from wich the qty is below the indicated stock limit, lists all books starting from books with the higher qty in stock to lower qty.

The error generated by Tomcat says:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /inventoryReport.jsp at line 22

19: <div>
20: <ul>
21: 
22: <x:forEach var="book" select="$doc/inventory/book">
23:    
24:     <li><x:out select="$book/title" /></li>
25: </x:forEach>
```

I tried to analyse this error but couldnt see what went wrong since i'm new to all this.

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<inventory>
  <book>
    <author>Pierre</author>
    <title>D&#233;veloppez vos applications web avec JRuby !</title>
    <date>Janvier 2012</date>
    <price>22</price>
    <stock>127</stock>
    <minimum>10</minimum>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>Paul</author>
    <title>D&#233;couvrez la puissance du langage Perl</title>
    <date>Avril 2017</date>
    <price>26</price>
    <stock>74</stock>
    <minimum>10</minimum>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>Matthieu</author>
    <title>Apprenez &#224; programmer en C</title>
    <date>Novembre 2009</date>
    <price>25</price>
    <stock>19</stock>
    <minimum>20</minimum>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>Matthieu</author>
    <title>Concevez votre site web avec PHP et MySQL</title>
    <date>Mars 2010</date>
    <price>30</price>
    <stock>7</stock>
    <minimum>20</minimum>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>Cysboy</author>
    <title>La programmation en Java</title>
    <date>Septembre 2010</date>
    <price>29</price>
    <stock>2000</stock>
    <minimum>20</minimum>
  </book>
</inventory>
```

My .jsp file

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Inventory report</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<c:import url="inventory.xml" var="documentXML" />

<x:parse var="doc" doc="${documentXML}" />

<p><b>List of all the books :</b></p>
<div>
<ul>

<x:forEach var="book" select="$doc/inventory/book">

    <li><x:out select="$book/title" /></li>
</x:forEach>
</ul>
</div>

<p><b>List of books that needs re-stock :</b></p>
<div>
<ul>

<x:forEach var="book" select="$doc/inventory/book[stock < minimum]">

    <li><x:out select="$book/title" /> : <x:out select="$book/stock" /> 
    books in stock (limit before warning : <x:out select="$book/minimum" />)</li>
</x:forEach>
</ul>
</div>

<p><b>List of books classified by stock :</b></p>



  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I event tried with a more simplistic exercise (see below codes)
But tomcat keeps returning this error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /inventoryReport.jsp at line 17

14: <c:import url="inventory.xml" varReader="monReader">
15: 
16:    <x:parse var="doc" doc="${monReader}" />
17:   <x:out select="$doc/news/article/auteur" />
18:    
19:    
20:
```

My xml file

```
<news>
  <article id="1">
    <auteur>Pierre</auteur>
    <titre>Foo...</titre>
    <contenu>...bar !</contenu>
  </article>
  <article id="27">
    <auteur>Paul</auteur>
    <titre>Bientôt un LdZ J2EE !</titre>
    <contenu>Woot ?</contenu>
  </article>
  <article id="102">
    <auteur>Jacques</auteur>
    <titre>Coyote court toujours</titre>
    <contenu>Bip bip !</contenu>
  </article>
</news>
```

My Jsp file

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Inventory report</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<c:import url="inventory.xml" varReader="monReader">

   <x:parse var="doc" doc="${monReader}" />
  <x:out select="$doc/news/article/auteur" />




</c:import>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is inventory.xml in a reachable (by the web app) location?

Comment: Yes, it's located in my webcontent folder (see screenshot)

Comment: I'm also getting a yellow warning on top of my jsp file saying : No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.

Comment: For grins, can you change, for now, the url to be fully qualified?  Like http://localhost:???/yourContext/inventory.xml?  Can you also try to access http://localhost:???/yourContext/inventory.xml from your browser?